# Who actually rested on the seventh day? Was it Memra or G-d, blessed be He?

Tags: shabbat, parshanut-torah-comment, tanach, pentateuch-chumash, targumin

[Targum Neofiti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Targum_Neofiti) states the following:

> “On the seventh day, the Memra of the LORD completed his work which he had created, and there was Sabbath.”  (Genesis 2:3; Targum Neofiti)

[Memra](https://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/10618-memra) is what "The Word" (or "Logos") is called.

According to the [Masoretic Text (MT) for Genesis 2:3](https://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0102.htm) however, it states the following:

> And God blessed the seventh day, and hallowed it; because that in it He rested from all His work which God in creating had made.

So who rested? Memra as perhaps a proxy of G-d, blessed be He or G-d, blessed be He, Himself?

Comment: If memra is a word employed by the Targum as a way of mentioning God (as per the link you provided: "a term used especially in the Targum as a substitute for "the Lord" when an anthropomorphic expression is to be avoided.") why do you think that there is a distinct identity which separates God and the expression of his power through "speech"?

Comment: @rosends Because other sources ascribe characteristics, behaviours, separate identity, etc. to it. Its not that simple. That article is merely a brief.

Comment: can you edit in some sources which establish that distinction?

Comment: Is neofiti even part of the Jewish mesorah ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Targum Yerushalmi you are quoting says that G-d rested, meaning ceased from new *speaking* like during the previous six days. See the alternate textual form, איקריה די״י.

It is also important to recognize that unlike with human speech, G-d's speech (words) don't cease during rest. So this emphasis on the Text is that innovation and/or change stopped during Shabbat, but Creation is continuous.

Here is a link to the text of [Targum Yerushalmi](https://mg.alhatorah.org/Dual/Targum_Yerushalmi_(Neofiti)/Bereshit/2.1#m7e0n6).